# downgrade new laptop to windows 7 using clean install

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, drivers, downgrade

I bought a new Medion laptop with Windows 10 already installed. For many compelling reasons I don't like win10. I tried to install win7. First I had to modify my ISO USB stick to include a driver for USB 3.0 port in order to get started. You can download a 'USB creator' utility (from Intel) to do this. I used: [Windows 7* USB 3.0 Creator Utility](https://goo.gl/QEjKF7)
I was then able to do a clean install of win7. But unfortunately I couldn't find any win7 drivers in order to get my wifi adaptor working. Without internet I was stuck! With regret I have now reinstalled win10. Does anybody know how I can find Win7 drivers for a Medion Akoya E3269 laptop?

Comment: Try connecting your PC via LAN and fetch the WiFi drivers via Device Manager. LAN almost always works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Try [**Snappy Driver**](https://sdi-tool.org/download/). I assume you have a fast internet so download the full version **(it is 12GB though)** while you're at Windows 10 then after downloading save it to another storage device then go ahead and install Windows 7 then use Snappy Driver to install all the drivers or you can download the Lite version and launch the software to download all WLAN drivers if that's the only driver you need

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out what kind of Wifi chip is installed. You may be able to get this info somewhere from Device Manager or try the manufacturers website. After that google to find Windows 7 drivers. If you're unlucky it's possible that the wireless chip is so new that Windows 7 drivers were never created for it. It's likely though that it's a common wireless chip, like Intel and you should be able to find drivers once you identify what it is.